# Unpacking a program which seems to be not packed?

Tags: unpacking, visual-basic

I have downloaded a sample of a malware to analyze it. First, I opened it with PEiD to look if it is packed. 
PEiD gives me the following information:

```
   Microsoft Visual Basic 5.0/6.0
```

So, I assumed that it is not packed. 
When I opened it using ollydbg shows me the following lines:

```
   PUSH malware.00401F8C
   CALL <JMP.&MSVBVM60.#100>
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   INC EAX
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   ADD BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],AL
   DB 00
   DB 1D
   ....
   ....
```

So, normally it should start with a function prologue(the typical beginning line with PUSH EBP and so on) but although it is not packed, obviously the program tries to make the analyzing process harder (for me). 
When I step to the second line( CALL <...>), then the process begins to run and does not stop. In my previous cases, I have only unpacked malware samples that were packed with UPX. So, a piece of code like that above is completely new for me. So:

How should I solve this? Can someone give me an advice how I can handle that?

best regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your program is not packed, but rather compiled as [Visual Basic P-code](http://www.woodmann.com/crackz/Tutorials/Vbpcode.htm) or Visual Basic native code.

If it's VB native code, you can use your favorite debugger (OllyDbg, IDA, etc.) to debug it, and IDA to disassemble it.

If it's VB P-code, you can use [VB Decompiler Pro](http://www.vb-decompiler.org/) to disassemble/decompile it:
[image: VB Decompiler Pro]

... and [WKTVBDE](http://blackfenix.fortunecity.ws/wktvbdebug/index.html) to debug it:
[image]

Note that VB Decompiler Pro is useful even for statically analyzing VB native code.

Comment: Not necessarily P-Code. Native VB has the same kind of entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks, @IgorSkochinsky, you're right. I've updated my answer above. I guess it shows how long ago I had to deal with VB targets :)